# Timedelta operation yields wrong results

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to add a column to a data frame that indicates the time difference of each rows index and a fixed timestamp. The data frame consists of a datetimeindex and some string columns.

I use

```
 d["diff"] = d.index-t0
```

to calculate said time difference. Due to prior filtering, the biggest possible diff value should be between 10 and 20s. However, I frequently get diffs slightly under a day (1-10s less), even though the actual difference is something like 5s.

I read that a prior version of pandas had issues with exactly this, but it was said to be long fixed.

My workaround would be to copy the index, cast it to int64, cast t0 to int64, substract t0 from all rows and then convert the diff column back to timedeltas, but that seems extremely inefficient and ugly.

PS: It happens on OS X and Debian 8 both using pandas 0.16.0.

EDIT: As requested, one sample:

```
2013-12-12 13:50:48 # t0
timestamp
2013-12-16 13:50:52   4 days 00:00:04
Name: diff, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

And I just noticed, the date is totally off, I use indexer_between_time() to get the indices and only looked at the time, not the date. This is even more confusing.

```
indices = df.index.indexer_between_time(start_time=index,end_time=index+DateOffset(seconds=t_offset) )
```

Comment: Example with sample data would be useful.

Comment: Are you aware of the way negative timedeltas get printed oddly? `pd.Timedelta(seconds=-0.5)` yields `Timedelta('-1 days +23:59:59.500000')`, because it always tries to keep the seconds value positive when printing. Is that what you're seeing, or something else?

Comment: Added a sample and a plot twist.

Comment: Are you sure that `between_time` is what you want? From the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html), it will give you all the times between those hours of the day, over all days. I think maybe you want `indices = df.index[index:(index + DateOffset(seconds=t_offset))]`, which will give you just times between your given endpoints on that particular day.

Comment: Yes, I seem to have misinterpreted the docs. Your way works, as far as I can tell so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the eventual cause of this was that you were using `between_time` to find times in your desired range. Unfortunately, `between_time` doesn't actually find times in a range, it finds times matching the same hours of the day, regardless of the day (I have definitely made the same mistake before). To find just the times in a specific range, you can just do:

```
end_time = index + DateOffset(seconds=t_offset)
df.index[index:end_time]
```

This works as longs as your `DateTimeIndex` is monotonic/sorted, if not you may want to sort first.

Comment: I had to change it to df[ (df.index>index) & (df.index<end_time)   ] because of missing values.